# MySQL: How to select identical value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a cell value in mysql table `85,77,25` datatype is VARCHAR. I'm targeting to select all having 85 identically, but I'm thinking if the 85 value increase to `185` or other number more than 185 that also contain 85, and I'm using `LIKE` operator in where clause. How can I properly select all of cell value having 85 only not 185, 285 and so on.

Example I have 4 rows and the value is

```
1. 20,85,77
2. 85,60,120
3. 10,4,85
4. 50,61,285
```

I need to get only those having '85' so the result should be from 1 to 3, I'm trying to combine LIKE operator beginning,ending and containing.

```
SELECT * from icweb.tbl_message 
where 
(to_id LIKE '%85' and to_id LIKE '85%' and to_id LIKE '%85%')
```

Comment: whats wrong with `SELECT * from icweb.tbl_message 
where to_id LIKE '85%'` ?

Comment: @AgamBanga If the cell value starts from 20,85 the beginning will be 20 not 85

Comment: ohhh! got the requirement.

Comment: I have added an answer. Please check if it works for you

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: @Strawberry I agree but i'm tired to create new table for 1 process so I was looking if there's alternative solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
SELECT * from icweb.tbl_message  
where 
(to_id LIKE '%,85' OR to_id LIKE '85,%' OR to_id LIKE '%,85,%' OR to_id = '85')
```

Comment: @HiFlyerOjt Glad i could help.